# why their is difference in output of ruby script?

Tags: ruby, linux, multithreading

I have follwing ruby scripts
rubyScript.rb:

```
require "rScript"
t1 = Thread.new{LongRunningOperation(); puts "doneLong"}
     sleep 1
     shortOperation()
     puts "doneShort"
     t1.join
```

rScript.rb:

```
def LongRunningOperation()
  puts "In LongRunningOperation method"
  for i in 0..100000
  end
 return 0
end
def shortOperation()
  puts "IN shortOperation method"
  return 0
end
```

THE OUTPUT of above script i.e.(ruby rubyScript.rb)

1) With use of sleep function

```
In veryLongRunningOperation method
doneLong
IN shortOperation method
doneShort
```

2) Without use of sleep function i.e. removing sleep function.(ruby rubyScript.rb)

```
In veryLongRunningOperation method
IN shortOperation method
doneShort
doneLong
```

why there is difference in output. What sleep does in ablve case. Thannks in advance.

Comment: do you understand what a `Thread` is ?

Answer (score 2):

The sleep lets the main thread sleep for 1 second.
Your long running function runs longer than your short running function but it is still faster than one second.

If you remove the sleep, then your long running function starts in a new thread and the main thread continues without any wait. It then starts the short running function, which finishes nearly immediatly, while the long running function is still running.

In the case of the none removed sleep it goes as following:
Your long running function starts in a new Thread and the main thread continues. Now the main thread encounters the sleep command and waits for 1 second. In this time the long running function in the other thread is still running and finishes. The main thread continues after its sleep time and starts the short running function.

Comment: thanks for help. Can u tell how i can get second ouput without removing sleep 1 function? Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: Let your LongRunningOperation sleep aswell or make the loop bigger (like 1 million iterations).

For what do you need this specific output?

Comment: I need it for specific reason, Can u tell how to sleep LongRunninOperation aswell or i tried making for loop bigger but it is not giving expected output as you told.

Comment: You could add a "sleep(2)" in the LongRunningOperation and remove the loop entirely.

Comment: thanks for support, I have added the assignment statment in for loop that works fine. Now i have another problem that actually i have implementaion of LongRunningOperation and shortOperationin in C++ and in this case it is not working. .i.e. not getting expected output as output 2 with the use of sleep function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is another problem which does not belong to this question. If the answer I gave you did help you, then you should accept it.

Comment: ya, most thanks for your solution. I just ask some other quiry. If you the solution for this also then u tell me.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep 1` makes the current thread sleep (i.e. do nothing) for one second. So `veryLongRunningOperation` (which despite being a very long running operation still takes less than a second) has enough time to finish before `shortOperation` even starts.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep 1`

Makes the main thread to wait for 1 second, that allows `t1` to finish before `shortOperation` is executed.